# What to sell in the Trading Post?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've been clearing maps and getting a lot of drops, some equipment stronger than the one I already have, thus switching my equipment to get better. Sometimes, I get drops which I can 'sell as junk' at the merchant or put in my Bank as materials.

There are some items left. I always sell them at the merchant, but sometimes I wonder which items would make more profit in the Black Lion Trading Company. Which items should I sell there? For example wands, do they have certain attributes which are worth money? What should I look for?

Comment: Bags, Bags, Bags. In every MMO, you sell Bags the most. Obviously not the low tier ones.

Comment: I only had a bag drop twice, and I've had quite some hours. You mean I should craft those bags and sell them?

Comment: One possibility to make money, yes. But ofc only bigger bags will sell and getting a profession up can be quite expensive. But then it is not that bad at all. I am tailor and I sell around 2 18 slot bags a day. Also, always collect stuff like vegetables, wood and ores and sell those. They can make you good money. Never fast travel inside areas and collect what you see. Also, green and yellow items over lvl 70 should always be salvage with a master kit to get an orb out of it.

Comment: I've just read around a bit on the wiki, and I see how this can be very profitable. So, to gain gold, you advice to sell all the loot I get from drops untill I'm at least level 70? And after that, sell all loot (except for collectibles) and salvage the green and yellow items? The Trading Post will only be any real good for crafted items?

Comment: Why GW2 > Real Life: Have you ever tried to put your vegetables in the bank? _They won't let you_

Comment: @Alex what are you trying to say with your comment?

Comment: @Joetjah Just a joke - about how in GW you can put vegetables in the bank, which would be a very strange thing to do in real life.

Comment: @Alex You never know.. The one moment you are peacefully playing GW2 in your room, the next moment Charr invade your hometown and destroy everything you have. You can be glad you stored 3 flowers and a sandwich.

Comment: I'm still suspicious. I once deposited 4 perfectly good vegetables in my fridge and when I tried to withdraw them 3 months later someone had snuck in and replaced them with rotten versions! Probably a Thief.

Comment: Only sell items on the trading post where

(projected profit) - (listing fee) > (merchant value)

Comment: @Brian sounds reasonable, but what if nobody buys it? That's why I asked this question. Then I'd be stuck with items I even paid extra for.

Comment: The more people offering the item at the price you are, the lower your odds are of selling. For example, if there are currently 10,000 offered at the price you're offering it at, it probably won't sell. But if there's only 1 offered at the price you're offering, it probably will sell. Either way, you'll be more likely to make a successful sale by undercutting the lowest sale price by 1c. You still might not be able to sell if the price is trending downward though. If you want to guarantee a sale, you can always sell to the highest buyer. And don't forget you can relist for 5% of the price.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way that I sell extra items on the market is that I look at the items value on the tooltip. Then I `right-click` > `sell on market`, and if I can make more than that *including* the listing fee then I stick it on the market.

I tend to only bother listing green or better items, all other stuff I just sell to merchant.

As for things to look out for, the pricier items will have,
+Power +Precision +Crit ~ Berserker,
also look out for,
+Precision +Power +Toughness ~ Knight
+Power +Toughness + Vitality ~ Soldier

If you want to keep an eye on the market check this site, http://www.gw2spidy.com/

Comment: That's a nice site to have! Thank you for your insight.